# how to stop a timer and display the time with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

i have a function that run and display a timer 
and i have other function that i want it to stop the timer and display the time when the user enter some code

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("October 22, 2017 20:24:00").getTime();

     // Update the count down every 1 second
     var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
   
   
    var sec = (distance/3000000);
 var seconds=sec.toFixed(3)
 
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="timer"
     
  
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =  seconds + " ₪" 
    
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
    }, 1000);


      function myFunction(){
    var b;

      // Get the value of the input field with id="entercode"
      b = document.getElementById("entercode").value;
      if (b==="7b358") {
  clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "timer is stoped";
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
      }}
```

```html
<input id="entercode" type="text" name="firstname" dir="ltr" placeholder="enter code"><input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
<div id="timer"></div>
```

why the second function dont work ?

Comment: works for me..... how ever you have to declare `seconds` outside

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/c6xLeehu/

Comment: its only show the string timer is stoped

Comment: i have to declare seconds outside in the first function or in the second function ?

Comment: yes because you have declare it inside setInterval function.so it's not available to `myFunction`.check my fiddle.declare it outside the setinterval function so seconds is available to both functions

Comment: outside the setinterval function but not inside myFunction.it should outside from both functions.